# Mining intermittently throughout the day

Tags: full-node

New to this and on a slow learning curve. Mining with cpu at approx 80-90 H/s. I only start the daemon when I am working on my computer. So on-and-off many times throughout the day. Besides being inefficient, will this prevent me from being rewarded with coins or will it just take a lot longer? Should I set the cpu never to go to sleep while mining?

Answer (score 1):

at that hash rate even running 24/7 you'll be lucky to make .5 coins in a year depending on your pool

if you're just having fun testing then go ahead

if you actually want to make coin you need a lot more hashing power - try adding at least one GPU

there should be no issue leaving your CPU (and GPU) running 24/7 running as long as you have enough cooling and airflow

Answer (score 1):

Specific to your questions:

> Besides being inefficient, will this prevent me from being rewarded
> with coins or will it just take a lot longer?

You'll want to be part of a pool and not solo mine. The consequence of your lower hash rate is lower earnings and likely a longer wait until the payments are released based on pool minimums. These minimums are not to be punitive but to control the number of microtransactions that would otherwise occur.

> Should I set the cpu never to go to sleep while mining?

Sort of a chase your tail question. If you want to mine, your CPU needs to be mining. (Not meant sarcastically) If that means you need to disable any sleep or other modes, then yes you'll need to do that. If your OS detects the CPU load (which it should), the CPU should continue to mine even with a display in sleep or powered off.

For anyone interested in helping a new pool get some traction, I welcome all to try newly launched:

**Gulf Coast Mining** (XMR)
https://mon.gulfcoastmining.com

Offering PPLNS & SOLO mining options.

Comment: Thank you, both. Great, informative forum. Yes, I was trying it just for fun and to get started somewhere. But I see now that this should be treated like a business just to get somewhere. An investment and go after hash power and pooling. In which case I see a new issue that other businesses do not have. At least as aggresively as it appears to be in this case. That is, the constant increasing need for more and more hash power just to remain at a certain production level. Which probably accelerates with time.

Comment: I'm not so sure it must be treated as a business. Exploring and trying at the low-cost entry of using existing CPU power makes perfect sense. You can then decide if you want to evolve into a hobby or something more. For example, I encourage all my Raspberry Pi3 owners to set up a storage card so the Pi3 can mine "all the time" when they aren't playing with it. It's nothing more (and nothing less) than a lottery ticket ... but some lottery tickets pay off (FWIW the cost per year to CPU mine 24x7 on a Pi3 is about $5 - odds are terrible, but odd things happen and you learn a lot).

Comment: Hey Mark... well, another interesting comment! Thank you. If you don't mind me asking, what peripherals do you recommend for the Raspberry Pi3? I am expanding my view to see this as a hobby. Much, much better from the perspective of learning and having fun. I do not know about coins... but the crypto field, in my layman view, is firmly here to stay so I appreciate any guidance. I went through the early stages of the internet in 1995/6. This looks bigger... in a way.

Comment: I hate to admit I predate the early internet ... suddenly I feel old. As per RP3 periph's, I think you'd be better served asking in a RP3 forum/thread as I really don't feel qualified to answer and you'll likely get a heavy mining bias here as it is monero focused. I can say I bought a RPZero for streaming video (prefer it over a chromecast) .. and an RP3 to mine as a lottery device. Other than the chassis I haven't gone down the road of other components. Good luck having fun!